# PHP : fread doesn't reads new line

Tags: php, fread

My file content is :

> TEST\nTEST2

When i open it with Notepad it shows :

> TEST
>
> TEST2

Ok. BUT when i do

```
echo fread($fp,filesize($fpname));
```

It shows :

> TEST TEST2

Why? Is there a way to read all text including line-breaks?

Comment: Are you echoing this inside a HTML document?

Comment: http://php.net/file_get_contents ; https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/pre

Answer (score 0):

Where are you echoing the output to? If you are outputting HTML then you need to replace the `\n` with `<br />` in order to see the breaks.

Comment: HTML. Yes. I just solved by myself. I just put echo "<pre>" . fread($fp,filesize($fpname)) . "</pre>";

Answer (score 0):

A simpler solution would be the following:

```
echo nl2br(file_get_contents($fpname));
```